# ArcGIS points to raster conversion with multiple fields in the attribute table

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, rasterization

I have 2,000 points each containing fields like day, month, year, time, brightness, name, serial, etc. But when I try to convert them to raster, only 1 field will be considered. Is there a way I can convert it to raster containing at least 4 fields? I use ArcGIS in the conversion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea of converting point feature into raster with only one field is to represent the pixel value with the selected field. That converted raster will be used later for analysis using raster calculator or any other spatial analysis that cannot be done using vector analysis tools.

You cannot click on any pixel and have several values simultaneously from several fields.

Thanks to @[Vince](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/21577/vince)'s comment, but if you want to use several fields, you need to convert each field as a separate raster, and each raster will represent one field. Then you can stack all raster images together using [Composite Bands](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/composite-bands.htm) tool. The output will be an image composed of several bands and each band represents one raster created from one field.

Comment: You can't have more than one variable in a single band, but you *can* have multiple bands. Not that a 20-band image with "name" as one of the bands makes sense for most GIS use.

Comment: @Vince Thanks to your valuable comment, I completely forgot about the stacking of raster images